# При вызове анонимного блока ошибка: Invalid column index

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jdbc

Есть рабочий анонимный блок:

```
DECLARE
    i_xml XMLTYPE;
    o_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    i_xml := XMLTYPE('<PARAMS> <ITEM_LIST> <ITEM> <APPL_NUM>01</APPL_NUM> </ITEM> <ITEM> <APPL_NUM>02</APPL_NUM> <BRANCH_CD/> </ITEM> </ITEM_LIST></PARAMS>');
    o_xml := DATA.SEARCH_API.search_by_appl('oracle', i_xml);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result=' || o_xml.getStringVal());
END;
```

Пытаюсь получить разультат следующим образом:

```
    CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(querySSl);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter("o_xml",Types.SQLXML,"SYS.XMLTYPE");
    ResultSet xmlClob = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
```

Пробовал так `? := o_xml`, пробовал менять типы. Всё одно, при попытке извлечь полученный результат, выводит ошибку:

> Invalid column index

Не понимаю, что не так. Как можно исправить?

---

PS Решил проблему:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(
    "{? = call DATA.SEARCH_API.search_by_appl.search_by_appl(?, ?)}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c2de27ede21594cb032e911735ba04a) вызова анонимного блока.

Функция, которая принимает и возвращает значения с типом данных `XMLTYPE`:

```
create or replace function me.getXMLType (xml xmlType) return xmlType as 
begin
    return xml; 
end;
/
```

Класс:

```
create or replace and compile java source named XmlTypeTest as
import java.sql.*;
 
public class XmlTypeTest {
    public static String exec (String xml) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ().defaultConnection ();
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        SQLXML xtret = null; 
        SQLXML xtpar = conn.createSQLXML ();
        xtpar.setString (xml);
        try {
            String plsql = String.join ("\n",
                "declare",
                "    xt xmlType := ?;",
                "begin",
                "    xt := xmlType ('<params>'||xt.getStringVal()||'</params>');",
                "    ? := getXMLType (xt);",
                "end;");
            cstmt = conn.prepareCall (plsql);
            cstmt.setSQLXML(1, xtpar); 
            cstmt.registerOutParameter (2, java.sql.Types.SQLXML);
            cstmt.execute ();
            xtret = cstmt.getSQLXML (2);
        }
        catch( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { if (cstmt != null) cstmt.close (); }
        return xtret.getString ();
    }
}
/
create or replace function getxml (par varchar2) return varchar2 as
    language java name 'XmlTypeTest.exec (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```
select getxml ('<a>aaa</a>') res from dual
/

RES
--------------------------------
<params><a>aaa</a>
</params>
```